# Can someone help me with understanding how servers work in java in the following code

Tags: java, client

this is a simple chat server and client i got from a book i've been reading and I'm having trouble understanding some of the code, can someone please help me with this problem

this is the client code here

```
public class ChatClient {
JTextArea incoming;
JTextField outgoing;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Socket sock;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
    client.go();

}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    incoming = new JTextArea(15, 50);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
    qScroller
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller
            .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    outgoing = new JTextField(20);
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(sendButtonListener);
    mainPanel.add(qScroller);
    mainPanel.add(outgoing);
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);
    setUpNetworking();
    Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    readerThread.start();
    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private void setUpNetworking() {
    try {
        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("connected");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

ActionListener sendButtonListener = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        writer.println(outgoing.getText());
        writer.flush();
        outgoing.setText("");
        outgoing.requestFocus();

    }

};

public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("read " + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
            }

            System.out.println("ggggggggg");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

the part that I'm having trouble understanding is this one:

```
public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("read " + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

in this part there is while code that is running as long as what we read from the server is not Null, my questions is won't the first thing that we read from the server as soon as we start the thread would be Null since we haven't written any thing to it yet, thus, breaking out of the loop?
like when would message equals Null?

this is the server code to whome ever wants to read it

```
public class ChatServer {
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket sock;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
        try {
            sock = clientSocket;
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChatServer().go();
}

public void go() {
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("got a connection");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

a way that would be more logical to me would be having a while true loop and checking the server all the time waiting for a message like this:

```
while(true){
    if ((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("read " + message);
        incoming.append(message + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"won't the first thing that we read from the server as soon as we start the thread would be Null since we haven't written any thing to it yet"* - I think you've answered your own question, in part.  `null` is returned from `BufferedReader#read` when it reaches the EOF, so, since `EOF` marker hasn't been reached, the `read` method will block until either there is something to be read or `EOF` is reached.  What book did you get this from? It's not a very good example

Comment: So theoretically, if there was to be an empty file and i invoke BufferedReader#read it wont return null? the book is Head First Java by the way :D

Comment: A `File` is different, if it was empty, the `BufferedReader` would detect the EOF and return `null`, a `Socket` is a different beast and doesn't have the same concept as EOF...typically you would send a "termination message" which the client would detect and they would both be able to terminate the connection in a graceful manner...

Comment: *"the book is Head First Java"* Really 8O ... It's violating the single thread rules of Swing...

Comment: Thank you so much dear sir everything makes more since now LOL. can you please explain how is the example violating the event dispatch thread rule?

Comment: Technically, `incoming.append(message + "\n");` should be called from within the context of the EDT, it could produce a race condition.  While, technically, the underlying document is synchronised, one should never assume that these methods aren't doing other things, but that's just me.

Comment: so what would be a good way to fix this from your point of view if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Personally, I'd use a `SwingWorker` instead of `Thread`, but that might be overkill for what you're trying to do, you could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and wrap the `incoming.append(message + "\n");` call inside it, as demonstrated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> won't the first thing that we read from the server as soon as we start the thread would be Null since we haven't written any thing to it yet

I think you've answered your own question, in part.  `null` is returned from `BufferedReader#read` when it reaches the EOF, so, since `EOF` marker hasn't been reached, the `read` method will block until either there is something to be read or `EOF` is reached.

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())...

> public String readLine()
>                  throws IOException
>   Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>   Returns:
>   A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination > characters, **or null** if the **end of the stream has been reached**

The loop is actually infinite.  The only way this will break is if the underlying stream is closed, which is likely to cause an `IOException`

What book did you get this from? It's not a very good example